# C++: Как распарсить json?

Tags: c++, json

Имеется примерно такая json строка:

```
{"response":[{"id":210700286,"first_name":"Lindsey","last_name":"Stirling"}]}
```

Как из неё получить значения `firstname` и `lastname`?

```
string firstname = "Lindsey";
string lastname = "Stirling";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь какой-нибудь библиотекой, например [`nlohmann/json`](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Обратите внимание, что в коде ниже используется [удобная запись](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) строковых литералов без экранирования в форме `R"(строка, которая может содержать кавычки. круглые скобки являются частью синтаксиса и не относятся к строке)"`.

```
#include "json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    string responseString = R"({"response":[{"id":210700286,"first_name":"Lindsey","last_name":"Stirling"}]})";
    json responseJson = json::parse(responseString);
    json object = responseJson["response"];
    string first_name = object[0]["first_name"];
    string last_name = object[0]["last_name"];
    cout << first_name << endl;
    cout << last_name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Вот пример работы](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M1pDJehyHJOFTt0O).

Comment: Кавычки можно не экранировать: R"(he say: "hello!".)";

Comment: ошибка no instance of overloaded function "nlohmann::basic_json

Comment: А в какой строчке?

Comment: json object = json::parse(response);

Comment: Попробуй обновлённый ответ

Comment: все ок только, string responseString нужно заменить auto responseString .спасибо

Comment: Скорее всего, нужно заменить `string` на `std::string`, либо написать `using namespace std`. Но `auto` тоже подойдёт, конечно.

Comment: Проблемы со string связаны msvc компилятором, в  gcc все ок

Comment: очень странно, ну да ладно

Answer (score 3):

как разработчик shell утилиты *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* предлагаю очень удобную (конечно это мое мнение) c++14 JSON библиотеку - [Json.hpp](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/lib/Json.hpp). Ваш пример с данной библиотекой будет выгдядеть вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "lib/Json.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

 string jstr = R"({"response":[{"id":210700286,"first_name":"Lindsey","last_name":"Stirling"}]})";

 Json j{jstr};
 string firstname = *j.walk("<first_name>l");
 string lastname = *j.walk("<last_name>l");

 cout << firstname << endl;
 cout << lastname << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
bash $ c++ -o e -std=c++14 example.cpp 
bash $ e
Lindsey
Stirling
bash $
```

Хотя, можно было-бы конечно так же легко получить эти значения через прямую аддресацию:

```
 string firstname = j["response"][0]["first_name"];
 string lastname = j["response"][0]["last_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще одна не плохая библиотека [vCjson](https://github.com/as-yuschenko/vCjson).
Решение вашего вопроса будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "../vCjson.h"

int main()
{
    char data[] = "{\"response\":[{\"id\":210700286,\"first_name\":\"Lindsey\",\"last_name\":\"Stirling\"}]}";

    vCjson json = vCjson(); //Create an instance of the class

    if(json.parse(data)) return -1; //parse
    if (!json.go_node_name("first_name")) printf("%s\n", json.get_node_value_str()); //find first_name
    if (!json.go_node_name("last_name")) printf("%s\n", json.get_node_value_str()); //find last_name

    json.~vCjson();

    return 0;
}
```