# "парсинг" json-Текста

Tags: c++, c, json

Столкнулся с такой небольшой проблемкой, вот мне приходят сообщения в видео json-текста, к примеру такое:

> {**requestId**:EBFEE62,**loaderId**:EBFEE62F1,**documentURL**:[http://mail.ru/,**request**:**{url**:http://mail.ru/,**method**:GET,**headers**:{**Upgrade-Insecure-Requests**:1,**User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0](http://mail.ru/,**request**:**%7Burl**:http://mail.ru/,**method**:GET,**headers**:%7B**Upgrade-Insecure-Requests**:1,**User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0)
> (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/97.0.4692.99
> Safari/537.36},**mixedContentType**:none,**initialPriority**:VeryHigh,**referrerPolicy**:strict-origin-when-cross-origin,**isSameSite**:true}**,timestamp**:179248.802265,**wallTime**:1650877930.53811,**initiator**:{**type**:other},**redirectHasExtraInfo**:false,**type**:Document
> **frameId**:4813D67ACC4FC0A38427D6C5067D4EFB,**hasUserGesture**:false}

Жирным выделены название параметров, через двоеточие идут значение этих параметров, запятая, как разделитель этих параметров.

Мне необходимы разделить параметры и их значения, ну то есть поместить имена параметров в один массив, а значения в другой соответствующий массив.

Сначала я думал все будет легко, сделаю split по запятой - выделив связку - "парметр:значение".
А потому сделаю еще один split по двоеточию каждого такого "парметр:значение", но тут я увидел, вот эту часть текста:

> (KHTML, like Gecko)

То есть внутри значения может быть запятая, а, если так - то я ни как не могу сообразить, а как же мне тогда разделить связку "парметр:значение" ?

Comment: есть готовые библиотеки по парсингу json

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674015/c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json
Похожий вопрос

Comment: Боюсь, это не JSON. В нем строковы значения (в которых может быть запятая) обязательно в кавычках.

Comment: Похоже, что такой текст надо парсить посимвольно. Например, по следующему правилу -- **параметр** (кроме первого) это *слово* (начинается с буквы или все символы только буквы (?)) в последовательности *запятая, слово, двоеточие* (возможны ли пробелы, табуляции и т.п. в ней, решите сами). Соответственно **значение** -- это текст между *двоетеочием* и запятой от следующего  параметра (у последнего значения надо выбросить `}` в конце). Наверное, в несколько десятков строк кода (сильно зависит от обработки ошибочных ситуаций) такой алгоритм уложится

Comment: @Chorkov, спасибо! Я не обратил на это внимание Тот текст который я скопировал уже был прощен через replace и все символы кавычек - уже были удалены. Теперь понятно, как разделить.