# Как работает сериализация/десериализация json в С++?

Tags: c++, c, json

В языках с рефлексией мне кажется все очень просто, получил имя переменной или из аннотации вытащил и распарсил строку, а как это в C++? Нельзя же получить в runtime имя переменной в структуре, то есть мне нужно уже заранее знать формат входящего json и настраивать маппинг? Есть же какие то наверно библиотеки которые json мапят на класс, типа как в java Jackson, и вот интересно как устроена эта логика в C++ или как это нужно было бы реализовывать в C?

Comment: Вопрос с готовым решением:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674015/c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674015/c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json)

Comment: Иногда можно макросом

Comment: https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons работает через макросы. Можно использовать кодогенерацию через внешние утилиты(не встречал таких пока что)

Comment: Есть два нормальных решения - сделать свою собственную рефлексию на макросах, либо парсить свой собственный код во время сборки (через libclang), чтобы сгенерировать нужную информацию для рефлексии.